# Does sup $a_n$ $\le$ sup $b_n$ implies lim sup $a_n$ $\le$ lim sup $b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am be able to prove that $\exists k \in N  $ such that $\forall n \ge k$, sup $a_n \le $ sup $b_n$ for all $n\ge k$. However, I need lim sup $a_n$  $\le$ lim sup $b_n$ as $n$ to $\infty$. Can I just take the limit and get the answer right away?

Comment: Nope, that isn't true. Let $b_1=1000,\;b_{n>1}=0$, while $a_n=1$.

Comment: Hi. I just edited my post to make it more clear. I have sup $a_n \le$ sup $b_n \forall n \ge k$

Comment: I believe it is true if you use the definition of limsup as follows $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{j\geq n}a_{j}$